# content is overlapping the header in html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a html code with bootstrap affix header. Below the header content added. It is working correctly when content is in single container. If I try to add container with column grid, those grids are overlapping the header. Please check the links.
[Before adding column grid](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FE0X0MOYHZR4) and [after adding the column grid](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEBO4G4P4H57). Hope anyone can give tell me how to code to fix this issue.

Comment: I wonder why you have included JavaScript code from `https://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com` in your example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving z-index to the .navbar will solve the issue.

```
.navbar{
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes. It worked. Thank you very much. You saved my time.

Comment: Always happy to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

just add an attribute z-index in css

```css
.navbar{
  z-index: 100;
}
```